# Accessing external parameters/values within HttpClientFactory definition in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I've an httpclient which uses Polly policy :

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", (serviceProvider, client) =>
        {
            var X = External_PARAMETER;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);
            .....
        })
        .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
        .AddPolicyHandler((provider, httpRequestMessage) => GetTokenPolicy(provider, httpRequestMessage));
```

When creating the clienthttp from this named client, I want to dynamically pass some paramters to it like:

```
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient", External_PARAMETER);
```

I know that one solution is actually to use a **singleton service** like this and pass values:
*As far as I know you can't use a transient or scoped service inside AddHttpClient definition. If I use a non-sington one I get this error (Cannot resolve scoped service 'MyApp.IMyService' from root provider.))*

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", (serviceProvider, client) =>
        {
            var passedServer = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
            var X = passedServer.GetMyParameter();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);
            .....
        })
        .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
        .AddPolicyHandler((provider, httpRequestMessage) => GetTokenPolicy(provider, httpRequestMessage));
```

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
.
.
.
myServiceInstance.SetMyParameter("A_VALUE");
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");
```

But how can I achieve this without using a singleton service like MyService?

There are cases where the HTTP request should create an HttpClient and having a sington service means all request will have access to this singleton service which is not ideal.

Comment: Why don't you set that value on the result of `CreateClient`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we could try to set the  DelegatingHandler for httpclient and this DelegatingHandler could be registered as the Transient.

More details, you could refer to below example:

Handler：

```
public class TraceLogHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ILogger<TraceLogHandler> _logger;
    private readonly bool _canLog;
    private StringValues ipAddress;

    public TraceLogHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<TraceLogHandler> logger)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public TraceLogHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<TraceLogHandler> logger, bool canLog)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _logger = logger;
        _canLog = canLog;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // here you could modify the http request
        int i = 0;

        return new HttpResponseMessage();
        //blah blah code for custom logging
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<TraceLogHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<ICountryRepositoryClient, CountryRepositoryClientV2>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler((services) =>
    {
        return new TraceLogHandler(services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>(),
                                   services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TraceLogHandler>>());
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how does this answers the OP's question. Could you please extend your answer from this aspect?

Comment: OP requirement is wants to dynamically pass some paramters to clienthttp. But he couldn't use Transient service to get the parameter and added into it. But the AddHttpClient service has the AddHttpMessageHandler which could modify the httpclient each time when the httpclient wants to send the request. During this time, he could modify the http header or anything by using the handler. Besides, this handler could be registered as the Transient. He could modify the service to add some parameter or pass some parameter to the send method and this service will be Transient.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in .NET.

Instead of creating one singleton service providing the value, it enables you to create and access a set of named singleton settings, so you could create one setting per named HTTP client:

```
class MyHttpClientOptions
{
    public string BaseUri { get; set; }
}

services.Configure<MyHttpClientOptions>("MyClient", opt =>
{
    opt.BaseUri = "https://url1";
});

services.Configure<MyHttpClientOptions>("MyClient2", opt =>
{
    opt.BaseUri = "https://url2";
});
```

You can access the named settings when creating the `HttpClient`:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", (serviceProvider, client) =>
{
    var options = serviceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<MyHttpClientOptions>>()
        .Get("MyClient");

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(options.BaseUri);
});
```

**UPDATE**

If some values really have to be fetched from the request's context, and can't be set to the client from where it gets created, you could add a custom builder which uses `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient1");
services.AddOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>("MyClient1")
    .Configure<IHttpContextAccessor>((opt, httpContextAccessor) =>
    {
        opt.HttpClientActions.Add(client =>
        {
            var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

            // If you have scoped service to create in the request context
            httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MyScopedService>();

            // Shared key value pairs
            httpContext.Items["some key"]
        });
    });
```

Comment: but how can I pass some values when creating the httpclient (client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");) ? so at the time when I define the named client 'services.AddHttpClient(...)' I'm not aware of those values.

Comment: If this is the case, why you'd pass the values to the client factory? Why not set the values to the client created? The client has transient lifetime, so setting values to one won't affect others.

Comment: thanks, yes it's correct. but how can I pass values to the client factory and then reference it within AddHttpClient code?

Comment: If you really needed to pass scoped parameters to HTTP client factory, you might need to use `IHttpContextAccessor` in the `AddHttpClient` code to access the request's context and get the values from the context.

Comment: Brilliant! It's a good idea to use httpcontext and works as I expect. I have another use case when accessig this named httpclient. It is actully exposed as a dll file and can also be used inside a background process. There are multiple cron jobs which run concurrently and will access this named httpclient as well. It looks like httpcontext doesn't exist when creating httpclient in a process or backgorund job (Hosted Service/Cron job). Any idea how to resolve this as well? thanks